# How to split a line of HTML code with multiple elements into multiple lines?

Tags: html

I have copied and pasted from the inspect html inside chrome into an editor.  But instead of splitting up the code into multiple lines with one div per line all my 100 div elements is in the same line.

How can I easily split them all up so they all get placed with one `div` per line?

If this is an editor thing then I am using Visual Studio Code.

The code that I pasted from chrome:

```
<div id="r201" class="ruta"></div><div id="r202" class="ruta"></div><div id="r203" class="ruta"></div>
```

How I would like it to be:

```
<div class="ruta"></div>
<div class="ruta"></div>
<div class="ruta"></div>
<div class="ruta"></div>
<div class="ruta"></div>
```

Comment: this is an editor thing. I would select the following pattern `</div><div` and repeat the selection until I reach the end of the file. The position the cursors between `><` and press Enter. How to repeat selection depends on your editor. If that was your question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly my question. I use visual studio code. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with VS Code to tell you exactly how to do it. You should research what are the short keys for doing such things. In Webstorm, which I use most, it is ^+G (or cmd+^+G if you want to select all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a one time format perhaps a site like https://regexr.com can be of use.

Effectively you find every `</div>` in the input text and replace it with `</div>\n`. The `\n` writes a new line to give you the formatting you need.

1. Enter the regular expression `<\/div>` in the regex pane.
2. Enter the text you want to modify in the middle pane.
3. In the tools pane select "replace" and enter `$&\n` (repeat the value that was found and append `\n` after it.

In the output you should get the values you're looking for.

If you need something VSCode, try the [prettier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

Answer (score 0):

I have perfect solution for your question,
from single line to multiple line in vs code .

Step 1:- go on vs code editor and type **Fn+F3** or **F3** .
You will be getting this.....
[Click Here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJGwH.png)

Step 2:- After getting above panel , Enter this **><**  on search bar and search it .

Step 3:- Replace it with **> *A line Break* <** For Example see below image..
[Click here to get the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzfMQ.png)

step 4:- Last Step ,Now Replace All **(ctrl+alt+enter)**

Comment: Try avoid posting links to pictures, in the long terms they won't survive and break.
Also, you can't assume the user(or other followers) will use VS code, try to supply a wider answer that fits all

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find the feature within Code, but in the regular Visual Studio it is in the menu under `Edit` -> `Advanced` -> `Format Selection`.